# .net Core Pipeline in azure devops

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-devops, yaml

I am new to working with Azure DevOps.
I am trying to create a pipeline in order to compile a Visual Studio 2022 solution.
In order to do this, I have to install NuGet packages from a remote server (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) and also from a local directory (packages stored on my repository).
Here my Yaml file

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    packagesToPush: ' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuPackages/*.nupkg'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

When I launch my pipline, the remote package are installed but not the local ones.

```
> Installed:
>     158 package(s) to D:\a\1\s\****.csproj
>     212 package(s) to D:\a\1\s\****.csproj
>     158 package(s) to D:\a\1\s\****.csproj
> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1101: Unable to find package UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.BouncyCastle. No
> packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg NU1101:
```

I've also tried to do this in two steps, but I had the same problem
If anybody have an idea, it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have your nuget.config. Yml file become

```yaml
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.Config'
```

and in the same location of your yml file add a Nuget.config with all your value:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="DevExpress" value="https://nuget.devexpress.com/xxx/api" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this task :

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
```

to make sure you have the pipelines has access to your nuget repos.
Following this official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

Also make sure the nuget repos are within the sources of nugets in your code (project/.nuget/nuget.config) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Nuget v2" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" />
    <add key="Nuget v3" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="your nuget repos" value="https://nugetreposlink/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```